# How to use content with HTML inside JSON data with nunjucks and gulp-data?

Tags: javascript, html, json, gulp, nunjucks

how to use HTML with JSON with [Gulp-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-data) ? I'm using it in a static website building process with Gulp,  [Nunjucks](https://github.com/carlosl/gulp-nunjucks-render) and [MJML](https://github.com/mjmlio/mjml/blob/master/packages/mjml-core/src/README.MD)

JSON

```
{
 message:"Welcome to <span class='red'>world</span>"
}
```

.nunjucks file

```
{{ message }}
```

is giving this output in final HTML output

```
Welcome to &lt;span class=&#39;red&#39;&gt;world&lt;/span&gt;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like Nunjucks uses `autoescaping: true` by default (due to their docs).

`gulp-nunjucks-render` uses `envOptions` to configure template engine (line 20 of its code).

You can try to pass `autoescaping: false` in options in gulp to disable escaping (more info in [readme](https://github.com/carlosl/gulp-nunjucks-render#options)).

Or you can just use `{{ message | safe }}` in your template to disable escaping for one piece of code. Mode info in [API Docs: Autoescaping](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#autoescaping)

Comment: Seems to be "autoescape" now, not "ing". So a piped gulp task would look like this: .pipe(nunjucks({
            envOptions: { autoescape: false },
            path: [paths.views.templates]
        }))
 reference: https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api.html#opts-autoescape

Comment: @PeterLewis that looks like global config for the builder and for security reasons it's better to keep it as is by default. But single template output auto-escaping is still there - [API Docs: Autoescaping](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#autoescaping)